# probability question - election

Tags: probability

I do not know how to solve this unit:

Say, in the UK, 45% of citizens support the Conservatives, 32% support Labour, and 23% support
the LibDems.
In the last election, 50% of supporters of the Conservatives voted, 40% of Labour
supporters voted, and 30% of LibDems supporters voted.

What is the probability that a citizen voted?

Answer (score 3):

You may think of this as follows:

- 50% of the group $C$ (that represents the 45% of the population) voted.
- 40% of the group $L$ (that represents the 32% of the population) voted.
- 30% of the group $LD$ (that represents the 23% of the population) voted.

You would like to know what % of the population voted, and you can calculate it as:

$(0.5\times0.45+0.40\times0.32+0.3\times0.23)\times100 =42.2$%

You can guess the probability from here.